# Wait until a process ends

Tags: c#, .net, process

I've an application which does

```
Process.Start()
```

to start another application 'ABC'. I want to wait till that application ends (process dies) and continue my execution. How can I do it?

There may be multiple instances of the application 'ABC' running at the same time.

Comment: And if you want to do it asynchronously (i.e. raise an event after completion), you can [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13685290/1016343) at SO.

Answer (score 462, accepted):

I think you just want this:

```
var process = Process.Start(...);
process.WaitForExit();
```

See the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty0d8k56.aspx) for the method. It also has an overload where you can specify the timeout, so you're not potentially waiting forever.

Answer (score 150):

Use [`Process.WaitForExit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx)? Or subscribe to the [`Process.Exited`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited.aspx) event if you don't want to block? If that doesn't do what you want, please give us more information about your requirements.

Comment: definitely good info with Process.Exited, but the OP did say "wait"

Comment: @MikeM: Which is why I referred to `WaitForExit` first... in some cases you may want to execute more code when something finishes, but that doesn't mean you need to block the current thread.

Comment: If you are going to use the `Process.Exited` event, I believe that you have to configure the process beforehand by setting `Process.EnableRaisingEvents` to true. Though, considering that this question is over three years old, it may be that `Process.EnableRaisingEvents` was not a thing at the time of it's having been asked.

Comment: I wound up on this page looking for the name of the `Process.Exited` event. Thanks! +1 for completeness

Comment: (Three more years later...) Note that setting `Process.EnableRaisingEvents` throws a [`Win32Exception`](https://www.giorgi.dev/net/access-denied-process-bugs/) (Access Denied) (as does `HasExited`) if the target process is elevated. (At least it still does as of .NET Framework 4.8.)

Answer (score 41):

I do the following in my application:

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = executable;
process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
process.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = true;
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit(1000 * 60 * 5);    // Wait up to five minutes.
```

There are a few extra features in there which you might find useful...

Answer (score 23):

You could use wait for exit or you can catch the HasExited property and update your UI to keep the user "informed" (expectation management):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe");
while (!process.HasExited)
{
    //update UI
}
//done
```

Answer (score 13):

I had a case where `Process.HasExited` didn't change after closing the window belonging to the process. So `Process.WaitForExit()` also didn't work. I had to monitor `Process.Responding` that went to false after closing the window like that:

```
while (!_process.HasExited && _process.Responding) {
  Thread.Sleep(100);
}
...
```

Perhaps this helps someone.

Answer (score 6):

[Process.WaitForExit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx) should be just what you're looking for I think.

Answer (score 4):

Referring to the Microsoft example:
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.enableraisingevents?view=netframework-4.8]

Best would be to set:

```
myProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

otherwiese the Code will be blocked.
Also no additional properties needed.

```
// Start a process and raise an event when done.
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
// Allows to raise event when the process is finished
myProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
// Eventhandler wich fires when exited
myProcess.Exited += new EventHandler(myProcess_Exited);
// Starts the process
myProcess.Start();

// Handle Exited event and display process information.
private void myProcess_Exited(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
Console.WriteLine(
                  $"Exit time    : {myProcess.ExitTime}\n" +
                  $"Exit code    : {myProcess.ExitCode}\n" +
                  $"Elapsed time : {elapsedTime}");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like Jon Skeet says, use the `Process.Exited`:

```
proc.StartInfo.FileName = exportPath + @"\" + fileExe;
proc.Exited += new EventHandler(myProcess_Exited);
proc.Start();
inProcess = true;

while (inProcess)
{
    proc.Refresh();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
    if (proc.HasExited)
    {
        inProcess = false;
    }
}

private void myProcess_Exited(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    inProcess = false;
    Console.WriteLine("Exit time:    {0}\r\n" +
      "Exit code:    {1}\r\n", proc.ExitTime, proc.ExitCode);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question. Please refine your answer to solve the question

Comment: And now? maybe open vb and make the solution;)

Answer (score -5):

Try this:

```
string command = "...";
var process = Process.Start(command);
process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: What's the point commenting on an answer to an already answered question about the question already being answered? Not only have you wasted your own cycles but you've compelled me to waste mine too.

Comment: @AdamBilinski questions and answers are intended to be seen by other people that have the question not only the one who asked

Comment: @L3n I agree, but this answer is exactly the same as the accepted answer so it's pointless!

Comment: @AdamBilinski Oh yea didn't read your comment properly forgive me xD