# Wait for process to finish and then display message (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, process

I would like to be able to watch a process until it is terminated, and once non existent display a message, how could this be achieved?

Comment: Use the Process.Exited event.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wait until a process ends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147911/wait-until-a-process-ends)

Answer (score 11):

Create/Attach to the process and then either use `WaitForExit()` to block until it has exited, or use the `OnExited` Event if you don't wish your application to block while it's waiting for the app to exit.

I heartily recommend reviewing the documentation for `Process` - [right here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx)

Answer (score 9):

The .NET Framework has built in support for this. You need to use the [`Process.Start` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) to start the process, and then call the [`WaitForExit` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx), which will block execution of your application until the process you started has finished and closed.

Sample code:

```
// Start the process.
Process proc = Process.Start("notepad.exe");  // TODO: NEVER hard-code strings!!!

// Wait for the process to end.
proc.WaitForExit();

// Show your message box.
MessageBox.Show("Process finished.");
```

Related knowledge base article: [How to wait for a shelled application to finish using Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305369)

Comment: One can never overstate the virtues of Event handlers - and OnExited is a great option.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want to do:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process=new System.Diagnostics.Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "process.exe";
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
//process ended
MessageBox.Show("Process terminated");
```