# C# wait for external PID to exit

Tags: c#, .net, pid

How do I wait until PID (not started from program itself) doesn't exist any longer?
I want my program to get a PID from an external program via commandline parameter and just wait for it to exit and then do something.

I searched for it, but all I could find were examples where the process has been startet by the C# program itself. That's easy to manage ..

I was going with something like this, but it obviously doesn't work ..

```
Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessById(7860);
            if (pname.Length == 0)
                Console.WriteLine("nothing");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("run");
```

How can that be accomplished?

Comment: @RaymondChen: Thats not exactly the same as in the referenced question they are waiting for a process started in the very same code.

Comment: @wonko79: The part not addressed in the duplicate Q&A is the impossible part. The one where a random process magically finds the interested application's standard I/O handles, just at the right time, and uses them to pipe their process ID into.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6723758/902497) is the specific duplicate. "Create/Attach to the process and then either use `WaitForExit()` to block until it has exited, or use the `OnExited` event if you don't wish your application to block while it's waiting for the app to exit." This particular question is using the "attach" case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that easily by writing:

```
var p = Process.GetProcessById(7860);
p.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Are you the same @wonko79, that [just complained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39641494/c-sharp-wait-for-external-pid-to-exit/39641632#comment66586778_39641494) that the proposed duplicate wouldn't address the question? Only to post an answer that - by that same standard - doesn't address the question either. I don't get that line of reasoning. Unless you are another wonko79, of course.