# understand when user closes a window

Tags: c#, console-application

At the end of my c# console program, I have made a M file which graph a function in MATLAB, and run it this way:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process Mfile = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
Mfile.StartInfo.FileName = "M.m";
Mfile.Start();
```

Is there any way to write a code that when user closes that MATLAB window, a txt file opens?
I can open both files together but I'm really interested to know if it is possible to understand when user closes that MATLAB file.

Comment: Check out the accepted answer in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147911/wait-till-a-process-ends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Process.WaitForExit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx) method. As documentation says it should wait for the process you will transfer. 
The using should be like

```
Mfile.WaitForExit();
// here you can invoke Notepad.exe with your text file
```

Answer (score 1):

`Process.WaitForExit` is somewhat in the ballpark, but what you want is an event.

You can use `Process.Exited` to invoke a method once the process is closed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited.aspx

Comment: Process.WaitForExit done what i wanted exactly. but thanks very much, that was good too.