# Executing external process on concrete processor and wait for termination

Tags: .net

I am looking for execute an external program inside a .net application.

I need to assign a concrete processor to that program.
I need to execute the program several times and every time on a different processor.
I need to wait for external program termination.

To simplify I have done a small spike (console) app to work on it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace ExecuteExternalInParallelWithAffinity
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    var processnumber = i;
                    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                        {                        
                            Process p = Process.Start("notepad.exe");                       
                            p.ProcessorAffinity = (IntPtr)processnumber;
                        }).ContinueWith(t => 
                        {
                            Console.Out.WriteLine(string.Format("Process ended on processor: {0}", processnumber));
                        });
                }
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
```

**My questions:**
1.- Can I assign processor affinity *before* executing the process.
2.- In spite I am checkin `Notepad` on task manager, all of them are assigned to processor 0.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wait till a process ends](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147911/wait-till-a-process-ends)

Comment: There is not a good reason to start a process by another thread.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I have found how to wait for process ends, but still need to assign a process to concrete processor.  And, sorry I don't understand your second comment.

Comment: `Task.Factory.StartNew()` is spinning up a thread.  It appears that threads *only* use is to start a process.  This provides no benefit what so ever.

Comment: @ErikPhilips if do you have any other better solution to execute an external process assigned to a concrete processor, I will be glad to learn from it. Thanks.

Comment: What does the thread have to do with which processor the external executable runs on?  Those are completely independent of each other. The process starts and executes on it's own thread independent of the thread that started the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Process` class does not support setting certain settings before the new process starts. The native `CreateProcess` API does allow that, though. You'll have to use that one.

Start the process in a suspended state. Set all the settings you like. Then, resume it. That way all code in that process will run under the new settings.

Comment: Thanks @usr I am now looking for for an example on CreateProcess in spite I would not like to go out managed code.

Comment: You'll find such an example with your favorite search engine.