# C# Open excel sheet after user exporting grid view to this excel sheet in his hard disk

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a function to export a `GridView` to an excel sheet using:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write
```

I want to open excel sheet automatically after the downloading
I have the function to open excel file and it works fine But the problem I am facing is where to call this function?

When calling function that exports grid view to excel sheet--> browser let user save the downloaded file in his hard disk and in same time code calling the function to open the excel sheet. It does a misleading and throws an exception that it cannot find this file name.

What I want now is to know where can I call the function to open the excel sheet after the user save it to their hard disk.

Comment: try excel.Visible =true; where excel is Excel.ApplicationClass object;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wait till a process ends](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147911/wait-till-a-process-ends)