# How not to freeze in VB.NET while Process.WaitForExit()?

Tags: vb.net, user-interface, powershell

What I have:

```
Dim test As Process = Process.Start("powershell.exe", "-executionpolicy
remotesigned -file C:\temp\test.ps1")

test.WaitForExit()
```

Finally while wait for "test" to exit, my GUI freezes.
How to make it smooth?

Comment: Try to use Threading function in your application.

Comment: @eyeshield21 - What is "Threading function"?

Comment: Why have you posted a snippet of [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38144171/how-to-loop-smooth-and-correctly-in-vb-net) as a brand new question within a short time of each other?

Comment: This really has nothing to do with the PowerShell tag either...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) to run this code on a separate thread, currently you are running it on the UI thread which causes it to freeze.

This should get you started:

```
Private Sub startWorker()
    Dim powershellWorker As New BackgroundWorker
    AddHandler powershellWorker.DoWork, AddressOf doWork

    powershellWorker.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub doWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)
    Dim test As Process = Process.Start("powershell.exe", "-executionpolicy remotesigned -file C:\temp\test.ps1")
    test.WaitForExit()
End Sub
```

Comment: Good idea anyway :) The problem now is that I wanna change an textbox.text in the background worker. It gives me "
Invalid thread -border operation" as an error (translated with google). Can u help me there too? Thx alot btw for u help ;)

Comment: Sure, ask a new question and me or someone else will try to help you there.

Answer (score 1):

The test.WaitForExit() is a blocking method and it will block your UI thread. Try running the code in a parallel task and await it

```
 Dim task As Task = Task.Run(Sub()
     Dim test As Process = Process.Start("powershell.exe", "-executionpolicy remotesigned -file C:\temp\test.ps1")
     Process.WaitForExit()
     Return test
  End Sub)
 Dim test2 As Process = Await task
 // some code that will execute after the process completes
```

You might need to add the async key word to outer method declaration.

Please note that I am a C# person :-)

Comment: You never call `Process.WaitForExit()`. This will only wait for the code being executed (which is done in no-time). Create a task instead in which you only run `Process.WaitForExit()`.

Comment: I have forgotten to add that line there. Now it is better. Thx