# if else for run file and stream file generate vb.net

Tags: vb.net, stream

How to First Run File seconds stream file in text box via `if` and `else`

```
    If Process.Start("test.bat") Then
        Dim address As String = "id.txt"
        Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
        Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(client.OpenRead(address))
        TextBox1.Text = reader.ReadToEnd
    End If
```

**Note: text file generated via batch file.**

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147911/wait-till-a-process-ends

Comment: It is likely to be better to generate the data in your program instead of using a batch file to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try
    Dim proc = Process.Start("test.bat")
    proc.WaitForExit()
    Using client As New WebClient()
        TextBox1.Text = client.DownloadString(File.ReadAllText("id.txt"))
    End Using
Catch
End Try
```